# How can I remove SQL Server CE reference from my database after migrating to SQL Server?

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-migrations

I have a web application created using Entity Framework. The site was originally created using SQL Server CE, but I have since moved everything over to SQL Server. When I switched to SQL Server, I removed all references to SQL Server CE from my project, however when I try to add a new migration I am getting this error:

> Schema specified is not valid.
>   Errors: (0,0) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file.

I've discovered that if I create a new database and point my development system there everything works, but when I then point it back to one of my existing customers databases I get the error. It seems that the reference to `SqlServerCe.4.0` is somehow embedded in the `_MigrationHistory` table.

Is it possible to manually rebuild `_MigrationHistory` for my existing databases? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: The provider name is in your edmx file, you did not remove all references!

Comment: I am using Code First - there is no edmx file.

Comment: Oh. I think you need to start over with a new, initial migration

Comment: I think I've been able to get it to work by doing basically that. I created a new, empty database, then deleted my migrations folder. I then ran enable-migration and add-migration initialize again. In order to get my existing databases to work, I then dumped the __MigrationHistory table from the new database to a script and used it to replace the __MigrationHistory in an existing database, and it seems to be working.